# Pinned start menu/taskbar shortcuts gone

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, start-menu

I just restarted my Windows 7 PC to find all my pinned shortcuts have disappeared from the start menu and taskbar. I've looked here
`"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned"`
And it seems the shortcuts are still there. Is there maybe a service that isn't running, which is causing this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I would like to improve the link, this way we dont look up our username:

%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, sorted it. I just deleted the shortcuts in the folder above, and then added them again. Dunno what caused it though. Thanks.

Comment: You are encouraged to mark your own posts as answered if you figure out a way to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the theme when you set up (add it) the quick launch shortcut toolbar. Right-click on desktop, personalize, right-click on the top theme (the one you are using now) and press save. Add a name like `1` and ok. Your stuff won't disappear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer failed for this.
[But this worked!](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/975784)

Answer (score -1):

1. Login
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> then select Task Manager.
3. Go to the Applications tab at the top and click the New Task button.
4. Type `explorer.exe` and click OK.

Everything should now show up.

Comment: I would recommend re-reading the question bud. His task bar is there already :)

Comment: agreed with Luke the Canadian, i downvoted this answer.