# Cannot show any pinned application to Start Menu or Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

I am trying to fix a problem on a Windows 7 machine (which is not mine, so I don't know what it has been done on it, but it is in reasonably working shape and up-to-date with Windows updates and antivirus definitions).

The problem is that all pinned applications in Start Menu and Taskbar disappeared. If I pin any other application, it doesn't show up. The folders in `"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned"` still contain all the shortcuts, so it's just Windows not showing them.

As suggested in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/141710/pinned-start-menu-taskbar-shortcuts-gone), I tried deleting all shortcuts and putting them back, but it had no effect.  Another source on the Web suggested that the cause might be a deleted registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile` and suggested recreating it via regedit, but it is already there.

Edit: There appears to be more than that: apparently user settings are not saved, as I set up Firefox as the default browsing application but it keeps asking me that every time it is started. According to [this article in the MS kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169144), it might be because the current user is not member of the workstation's group Users. I fixed this but it didn't resolve the problem. BTW, the current user has Administrator rights.

Comment: Sounds like a good case to run SFC to verify the system integrity.

Comment: Done, no integrity violation reported. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have said it would.  If there were integrity violation, it might have, if there are not integrity violations then there was nothing to fix.  Does the owner use a program called CCleaner by chance?  When you manually put the icons in this folder, are they deleted, or do they simply not show up.

Comment: If I drag manually a program icon to the Start Menu area, it doesn't show up. However, I see that the shortcut is correctly created in `"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu"`.

Comment: Could be a corrupt profile. Go to `C:\Users` and see if there is any users called something like "TEMP".

Comment: There is no user dir called as such but it is definitely a corrupted profile: I'm experiencing a lot of glitches. I'll make a new profile and see how it goes.

Comment: hey, me too. i made it manually for the shortcut to be there... but no luck. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Microsoft bug that apparently has many reasons and solutions.
Here are some solutions that you could try, but there is no guarantee
that your problem is one of them :

1) [**Reset and Clear All Items in Windows 7 Jump Lists**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/81483-jump-lists-reset-clear-all-items.html)

Essentially, you must go to both:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
```

and delete all files from both folders (make a backup just in case).

2) Ensure that there is no product installed on the computer whose purpose is to
hide or lock folders.

3) [**Create a new user account**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-user-account#create-user-account=windows-7) and check if the issue recurs in it.
If it does not occur, it could indicate that your user account is corrupted.
Access this link and follow the steps to copy all files from the
corrupt user profile to the new one : [Fix a corrupted user profile](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7),
and in your case ensure also that it is an administrator account.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft` directory in  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData`. This dir contains the dirs `Local`, `LocalLow`, and `Roaming`.

Comment: `%appdata%` is a shortcut to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming`. It will work in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Some documentation I've found referred to `%appdata%` as the dir mentioned in my previous comment. Anyway, the `Recent` dir is empty. Inserting `%appdata%` in the address bar of Explorer returns a "not found" error; note that this machine has the Italian localized version of Windows 7.

Comment: I have no experience with the Italian version, but %appdata% must work or this Windows version is in really bad shape. If that's the case, see [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html), but ensure, just in case, that you have backups and can reinstall everything from scratch. The best backup is a disk-image backup taken from example by [AOMEI Backupper](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) (not by Windows Backup).

Comment: I'm going with #3. I've recreated the user profile and I've already seen that the original problem as well as the `%appdata%` problem have gone away.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 didn't work for me on Windows 10 Pro, and Step 3 is something that I don't want to try right now as I suspect there is a better way. I know I've fixed this before but can't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

1. Save your work & files & close all windows.
2. Use **<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>** shortcut to find **Command Prompt (Admin)** & run `REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F` to remove all pinned items.
3. Next, run `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` in command prompt with admin privileges  to **kill** Windows Explorer.
4. Click **<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>** & run `explorer.exe` or use command prompt with or without admin privileges to restart explorer  (you may also use Windows Task Manager to do this by clicking on **File** > **Run new task** > `explorer.exe` to restart Windows Explorer. Note: system restart *not* required)
5. Go to `"%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\"` & delete all shortcuts & files -- this should restore your taskbar to default state.
6. Try pinning your apps now -- should work for the windows taskbar atleast.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted as soon as I reach 15 reps. However, I'm going to go with @harrymc's solution and recreate the user profile as there are too many problems (courtesy of Microsoft) to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click any blank area of taskbar. Look for "Show application icons". If it has no checkmark, select it to add the check. God only knows why this option exists.

Comment: not found.any clue?